# A game where you could sell body parts for cash

Tags: apple-ii, identify-this-game, apple-iigs

Ages ago I played a scifi game on the Apple IIgs where you could sell body parts for cash. The game involved travel between planets and selling parts of yourself was a last ditch option to raise money for other things. The game was played on an Apple IIgs, but might have been a regular Apple II game. Could someone come up with a list of possible candidates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [*Neuromancer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuromancer_(video_game)) -- a 1988 game which was available on a variety of platforms including the Apple iiGS -- the player can sell their body parts for cash in the "Body Shop":

[image: "Can I be of service? Would you like to sell a body part?"]